# Can an axis web servcie be called from iOS platform using any library?

Tags: ios, web-services

As we have ksoap library for calling axis web services in android and blackberry platform, do we have anything of that kind to call an axis2 webservice.

Comment: sorry surya, In IOS we don't have this kind of library.

Answer (score 0):

I worked well with http://sudzc.com/ in a project.
On their site you can enter the url to your WSDL-file or upload it.
After pressing "generate" a personalized code with for your wsdl-file generated methods will be embedded in their framework.
unfortunately sudzc is only available as an alpha-version but I used it with any further problems.

Comment: i checked out the link that u provided. but that can generate the code only for the webservices which are online, i mean in the public domain. But my webservice runs in my local server (my own machine). How the site is going to connect my machine for the webservice and generate the client side code for the same. It's not working for that. Do you have any idea about such library?

Comment: I think it can work when you got a wsdl-file which you can upload to the site (it's a small link next to the headline "Type the web address of the WSDL to convert"). The site uses the definitions of the methods in this file to generate code that wrap "only" the methods of the framework. In a configuration part of the framework you can set the  url per parameter to your local machine. If that does't work (when you don‘t have a wsdl-file) you can maybe use the file from another web service to get the framework and use it as base for your own development?!